# ionicFramework vs Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ionic-framework, xamarin.forms, comparison

I want to build an application for all platforms but I wonder!

What is the difference between ionic-Framework and Xamarin.Forms and,

Which is better to build an application for all platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it mainly depends on what you want to do in your application.

If all you want to do is pushing some data and images (e.g. create a shop platform) i don't see any reason, why ionic wouldn't do the job and probably you'd see results a bit faster, as you don't need to struggle with a lot of native adaptions (such as file system access, etc...), though I don't think that choosing xamarin would set you back in terms of X months more.

However if it comes to using native features, such as camera, gps, sensors, whatever you will probably be limited to what the ionic api offers and I don't know how long the turnaround times will be until new features which may appear in the future are getting implemented into the framework.

Performancewise I am honestly sceptical if that mix of html, css and javascript/jquery will be anything comparable to what xamarin can get you to, as Xamarin actually produces an app which can compete with apps written natively.

I am not sure how deep you can get "under the hood" with ionic, though I know that with xamarin, you can actually go very deep and develop features that can use the native code of your target platform.

Actually by looking at the user base (or better to say the amount of questions here on stack overflow) one might be tempted that ionic has more questions than xamarin.forms, however that doesn't take into account that actually any question about xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios and c# might hold relevant answers and support for your upcoming problems. However to be fair, also ionic has quite an impressive amount of q&a answers posted here, so i would say that is a draw.

My conclusion would be: If you need to create a data-pushing app fast, you could use ionic, however if you need performance, native methods and want to be able to use particular native features, Xamarin would hold that door open for you.

Disclaimer: I have been developing apps with xamarin forms for about 5 years now and have never used the ionic framework at all and therefore my knowledge about ionic is limited to what I read on summaries. Probably my answer might omit particular benefits that ionic might offer and I really hope that a more experienced ionic developer might have something beneficial to add.

However, If you were asking about my personal advice, My answer would be: Use Xamarin

Comment: Why the downvote on this answer? I think he explained well enough. At-least this answer doesn't deserve Downvote.

Answer (score 2):

In the hands of skilled engineers, Ionic and Xamarin are both exceptional cross-platform development assets, which, compared with building native apps for two or more platforms, will save your business both time and money. Any decision about which one to use, though, should be subject to rigorous assessment of your needs, budget, and development objectives.

If app quality is a priority, you’re integrating with a lot of preexisting .NET architecture, and/or you need to build apps for a wide variety of platforms and versions, Xamarin will almost certainly be the best fit.

For smaller or less frequent projects on restricted budgets, Ionic will provide you with a fast and effective route to functional if unspectacular mobile apps for iOS and Android devices.

Depending on your resources, and whether you will develop apps in-house or with the help from external development companies, you might even wish to utilize both of these popular frameworks. Neither one is particularly costly to implement, especially since Microsoft started bundling Xamarin for free with the Visual Studio Community edition and Xamarin Studio (for Mac).

Answer (score 1):

We had to answer this question about 18 months ago.  For us the core question was if the app also needed to be deployed to a web environment.  In our case we needed to support the same functionality in a native iOS/Android app, as well as a website (for the features that the web can handle).  In that scenario Ionic is the clear winner.

If you don't have to worry about web, then I think Xamarin is a great option.  I'd also be checking out [Google's flutter](https://flutter.io/) too, which is a newer cross-platform option (again assuming no web needed).